# Rsync with multiple wildcards

Tags: rsync, remote-server

How can I rsync all files of multiple types from a remote server? E.g. I want to rsync all pdf's and png's from a folder on the server.

This raises a syntax error: `rsync REMOTE_SERVER:REMOTE_PATH/{*.pdf, *.png} LOCAL_PATH`

I've also tried:
`rsync --include='*.png' --include='*.pdf' --exclude='*' REMOTE_SERVER:REMOTE_PATH/ LOCAL_PATH` which syncs nothing.

I'm currently resorting to
`rsync REMOTE_SERVER:REMOTE_PATH/*.pdf LOCAL_PATH; rsync REMOTE_SERVER:REMOTE_PATH/*.png LOCAL_PATH` but would like to do this in one command.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with programming and is not suited for SO. It's even defined in the tag you've used... Please research your question over on superuser